# Use GoogleChart with data from firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I use angular cli 6, rxjs 6, angularfire2 and firebase . I want to use the GoogleChart API in angular 6.

My code works correctly with data written in hard in the component but I would like to use it with data from firebase.

Here's what works:

Component.html

```
<div>
  <app-gantt [data]="data1" [config]="config1" [elementId]="elementId1"></app-gantt>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
export class PpsComponent implements OnInit {

 patientid: string;
 ppssToDisplay;
 data1: any[];
 config1: GanttChartConfig;
 elementId1: string;

 constructor( 
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private location: Location,
    private ppssService: PPSsService,
    private router: Router, 
    ){ }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
   this.patientid = urlParameters['id'];});
   this.ppssToDisplay = this.ppssService.getPPSByPatientid(this.patientid);

   this.data1 = [[ 'treatement','dateA', 'dayeB'],
   [ 'Chirurgie',  new Date(2017, 3, 29), new Date(2017, 3, 30)],
   [ 'Chimiothérapie', new Date(2017, 2, 4),  new Date(2018, 2, 4)],
   [ 'Radiothérapie',   new Date(2017, 2, 4),  new Date(2018, 2, 4)]]; 

    this.config1 = new GanttChartConfig( '',new Date (),new Date ());
    this.elementId1 = 'myGanttChart';
```

Now, I would like to use the graph with data from firebase. Here is what I tried:

Interface.model

```
export class PPS
 {
 constructor (
 public Patientid : string,
 public treatement: string,
 public dateA = new Date (),
 public dateB= new Date (),
 public description: string,
 public effetsind: string ) {}
 }
```

Service.ts

```
    getPPSByPatientid(Patientid: string) {
      return this.database.list('/ppss', ref =>
      ref.orderByChild("Patientid").equalTo(Patientid)).valueChanges();
      }
```

Component.ts

```
export class PpsComponent implements OnInit {

patientid: string;
ppssToDisplay;
obj: any[];
data1: any[];
config1: GanttChartConfig;
elementId1: string;

constructor( 
  private route: ActivatedRoute, 
  private location: Location,
  private ppssService: PPSsService,
  private router: Router, 
  ){ }

ngOnInit() {

  this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
  this.patientid = urlParameters['id'];});
  this.ppssToDisplay =this.ppssService.getPPSByPatientid(this.patientid);

  let interestingFields = [ 'treatement','dateA', 'dateB'];
        this.ppssToDisplay.subscribe(obj => {
        this.data1 = [
        interestingFields,
        interestingFields.map(field => obj[field]),
        ];
        console.log(this.data1);
        });

        this.config1 = new GanttChartConfig( '',new Date (),new Date ());
        this.elementId1 = 'myGanttChart';
```

console.log(this.data1);

```
(2) [Array(3), Array(3)]
0:(3) ["treatement", "dateA", "dateB"]
1:(3) [undefined, undefined, undefined]
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Are there any errors in my code? (surely) or is there a simpler way to transmit data such as a ngfor loop?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same problem as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186182/8217812)(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186182/8217812).

Basically, the perspective from where your are mapping you data is wrong.

```
this.ppssToDisplay.subscribe(ppsList => {
  this.data1 = [
    interestingFields,
    ...ppsList.map(pps => interestingFields.map(field => pps[field]))
    ];
});
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I need to define pps and ppsList ? Thanks for your help

Comment: If this really is the same you should mark it as a duplicate instead of reposting your answer here.

Comment: How i do this ?

Comment: @andré-kool I don't have reputation to mark it as duplicated

Comment: @alNTM No, you don't have to define them. They are part of the anonymous function.

Comment: @NeryOrtez Woops my bad, I just responded without looking at your reputation. I just flagged it as a duplicate myself :)

Comment: @NeryOrtez Thank U Thank U Thank U I love U man !! I have the correct array : (3) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0
:
(3) ["traitement", "datedebut", "datefin"]
1
:
(3) ["Chimiotherapie", "2018-06-28", "2018-07-07"]
2
:
(3) ["Chirurgie", "2018-07-11", "2018-07-14"]
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: But i don't understand why the graph doesn't display..

Comment: @NeryOrtez Scuse me Nery. How i can pass the value of const data1 to this.data1 ?

Comment: Oh... My bad, I left `data` instead of `this.data` for testing pourpuses. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: It's the same. I think the value must be out of the fonction for the graph works

Comment: No, no... Instead you should leave the initializationg of the chart inside the function. That way the chart waits for the data.

Comment: @alNTM mail me neryortez@gmail.com